# What's with "killing you where you stand"?

Tags: stargate-sg1, star-trek-first-contact, black-panther-2018, archer

I have noticed the recurring expression "**I will kill you where you stand**".

The first is Worf in *Star Trek: First Contact*:

We also have Te'alc in *Stargate SG-1*:

And in *Black Panther*:

And finally in [*Archer*](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/embed/fb622bca-c6d2-4151-9c29-e87a983c48d3).

Is this a generally used expression (I've never heard it) or is it a common reference to some earlier work?   Or all they all based on the *First Contact* precedent?

Comment: Sorry -- having trouble getting a link to the clip from Archer -- any help appreciated.

Comment: It is quite common saying... really. I am not native English speaker and I've heard it plenty.

Comment: It looks like a long standing somewhat common expression: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kill+you+where+you+stand%2Cshoot+you+in+the+back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckill%20you%20where%20you%20stand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshoot%20you%20in%20the%20back%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Yasskier:   It's not common to me.   Maybe I'm not frequently threatening or being threatened with murder.    I assumed it was a brilliant Klingonism.

Comment: Ah yes, the thug life that I live :P  But seriously, I believe that I've heard it quite commonly in the Western movies or ones taking place around early 1900s

Answer (score 9):

It is quite common saying in English language meaning  "I am on the end of my temper, don't anger me or you will regret - I will kill you right here and right now".

The [Ngram search for this sentence in books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kill%20you%20where%20you%20stand%2Cshoot%20you%20in%20the%20back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckill%20you%20where%20you%20stand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshoot%20you%20in%20the%20back%3B%2Cc0) (kudos to jejorda) found that it originated somewhere [around 1830](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=75JFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA716&dq=kill%20you%20where%20you%20stand&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF6u_w5YjcAhXECcAKHfCDCAsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=kill%20you%20where%20you%20stand&f=false) (kudos to Valorum), but its popularity peaked somewhere around early 1900-1910. There is even a [painting](https://www.loc.gov/resource/cai.2a11779/) called "Do you wish me to kill you where you stand?"

Comment: From the 1830s; https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=75JFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA716&dq=kill+you+where+you+stand&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF6u_w5YjcAhXECcAKHfCDCAsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=kill%20you%20where%20you%20stand&f=false

Comment: The earliest I found in Google Books was 1835: https://books.google.com/books?id=dHEHAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA228&q="kill+him+where+he+stands"

Comment: I am trying to find it in the movies - so far the earliest is 1955 "Being Human"

Comment: Actually it is a threat that under certain circumstances, such as angering me even a tiny little bit more, I will instantly kill you.  Not kill you tomorrow, or next year, but right now before you can move a single step - if you do anything to anger me even a tiny little bit more than you already have.

Comment: @M.A.Golding point taken - edited.